# Is cowboy programming a senior approach?

Tags: development-process, development-methodologies, cowboy-coding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Frankly, do you prefer Cowboy coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7217/frankly-do-you-prefer-cowboy-coding)

By cowboy programming, I mean a programmer just typing the code very fast without a semi-formal process.

I have a programmer that codes fast by dismissing revision control, documentation, patterns, tests, and methodologies. We talked about that and she tells me that all the approaches like agile are too academic and disregards them completely. I feel very reluctant to believe that is the consensus among senior programmers. I used to bring samples of big-name-guys like Kent Beck and Alan Kay, but she tells me that those are just authors trying to sell books or professors with no real experience.

Yes, it is fast at first, but the time saved by the cowboy approach is paid in debugging. I'm not planning to change her opinion, but if those are bad practices, I don't want to adopt them.

See, as a junior level, it is hard to filter good and bad practices because your knowledge is mostly based on books or on people with more experience than you and they might be wrong as well. So to senior programmers, is this a common approach at your league?